# Pass more than one parameter by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a system where each user will have a subdomain and your own database. Ex:

```
usuarioa.system.com
usuariob.system.com
```

To keep the subdirectory on the navigation bar while browsing through the system, I used the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ usera.system.com $ [OR]
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.usera.system.com $
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ http://www.system.com/access/$ 1? user = usera [P]
```

It's working perfectly, because through PHP using $ _REQUEST, direct connection to the correct database. The problem is that this rule is not accepting more than one parameter and any changes I make, gives error 403. So I created a temporary solution in PHP, but I don't want to continue with her:

```
list ($queryString, $id) = explode ("user =", $ _SERVER [' REQUEST_URI ']);
list ($id, $idUsu) = explode (".", $id);
```

How could I pass 02 parameters directly via htaccess keeping the subdirectory on the navigation bar?

Sorry for my English, I am using Bing translator.

Comment: You have many _erroneous_ spaces in your code samples that are presumably not in your original code (as it would otherwise "break")?

Comment: _Aside:_ If you currently have separate directives (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) for each user (which would seem to be implied from your question) and these "users" all follow the same pattern, then you could potentially reduce these to a single rule block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ http://www.system.com/access/$ 1? user = usera [P]
> ```

If you are referring to passing additional query string parameters that were on the original request through to the *substitution*, then you need the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive.

The `QSA` flag *merges* the query string from the request with the query string you have specified on the *substitution*, otherwise, the query string you have stated will overwrite the query string on the request and it will not be passed through.

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.system.com/access/$1?user=usera [QSA,P]
```

---

*Aside:* This...

> ```
> RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^usera.system.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^www.usera.system.com$
> ```

Is the same as the following and also allows for FQDN (ending in a dot):

```
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?usera\.system\.com [NC]
```

Remember to escape the dots to match a literal dot, otherwise, you are matching *any* character. The `NC` flag is simply to catch malformed requests.

Comment: Hello MrWhite. Thank you very much. Worked perfectly! Greetings from Brazil.